# Navigation Alignment Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

Is it possible with css or maybe javascript/jQuery-manipulation to center some navigation items within the same div container, while other itmes in this container (last three) should be on the right edge of the navbar? I've tried it with flexbox and with inline-block/text-align center. I was able to center the whole div container. But when I moved the last three divs to the right, the remaining items stayed in their position. Based on the fact, that the three items now are on the right side, the width of the centered navbar changed and it should actually move a little bit to the right to be centered again.

Making new wrap elements around these centered and right side elements would be the last choice, since I am running on wordpress with php-menues. Therefore, changing the markup would maybe not so easy, like a simple css or javascript/jquery solution.
You may have a look at the fiddle below the posted markup to understand me better ;)

Default HTML-Markup:

```
<div class="header" style="height: 100px; overflow: visible;">
<div class="row">
<div class="logo" data-margin-top="34px" data-margin-       bottom="10px" data-margin-left="0px" data-margin-right="0px">
            <a class="logo-link" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
                    <img src="http://www.backstein.com/media/mobil_1376659435_test_logo_neu.jpg" alt="ava" class="logo-1x standard-logo" style="" height="33" width="45">
                </a>
</div>
    <div class="main-menu">
        <ul id="menu-mainnav" class="menu">
            <li id="menu-item-116" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-116 dropdown-menu">
                <a href="/link1/" aria-haspopup="true">
                    <span class="menu-text">CENTER </span>
                </a>
                </li>
            <li id="menu-item-263" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-263 dropdown-menu">
                <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" aria-haspopup="true">
                    <span class="menu-text">CENTER </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-75" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-75">
                <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
                    <span class="menu-text">CENTER </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27">
                <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
                    <span class="menu-text">CENTER </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76">
                <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
                    <span class="menu-text">CENTER </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76">
                <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
                    <span class="menu-text">TO RIGHT </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76">
                <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
                    <span class="menu-text">TO RIGHT </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li id="menu-item-133" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-133 menu-item-button">
                <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="menu-textmenu-text button button-default button-medium">TO RIGHT
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
       </ul></div>      

        </div>
```

Default CSS:

```
.header {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0px;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  width: 94.44444%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
 }

.main-menu {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 200;
  overflow: hidden;
}

 #menu-mainnav {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

#menu-mainnav > li {
 float: left;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: list-item;
 text-align: match-parent;
 padding-right:11px;
  }

#menu-mainnav > li > a {
 font-size: 11px;
 display: block;
 box-sizing: content-box;
 }
```

JSFiddle-Example: https://jsfiddle.net/tz0atc4o/1/

Update:
Here a fiddle, where I've tried the text-align and inline solution. You may read the CSS-Comments, so you are able to test the thing, when the whole div is centered. In this case just comment out the last css rule. In contrast the the whole centered div, I am not sure if the items are really centered, when the last three are floated to right :/

https://jsfiddle.net/37gc2v9x/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35250367/3597276

Comment: Hi, thanks! I've tried this with flexbox and margin: auto. The problem is that I have more than 1 last item, which should be on the right side. This leads to alignment issues in my test, but maybe I was wrong. I will give it another try in the evening, again :)

Comment: The number of items doesn't matter. Just apply the `margin-left: auto` to the left-most item in the group you want aligned to the right. Then make sure to add identical phantom items on the left. https://jsfiddle.net/nt4prkaq/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `float: right` to the last items and others make `display: inline-block;` and `float:none;` then only change .menu to `text-align: center;` and `width: 100%;`

Comment: Hi, I've already tried that, it could be possible that I have to go to the optician to get some glasses, but I am not sure, if the centered items are really centered when the other itmes are floated to the right. I've made a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/37gc2v9x/. While I am sure that the items are centered when the whole div is centered, I am not sure, if the items are really centered when the other itmes are floated to right? May you check please, if it is just some kind of optical illusion? For me they seems not to be centered. You may also check my css comments for understanding :)

Comment: usually when text-align: center is not centered right there is some margin or padding on the centered items. check this. I give you the suggestion how to reach the result, it will need some corrections like this one.

Comment: You were right, I had to eliminate some remaining paddings! Thank you very much, you made my day :)

Comment: @DoUtDes Please show the result. I can not get to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Hi Gleb, when every <li> item has 12px paddings on the right side, this padding has to be eliminated on the last item, which should be centered, otherwise it would move the whole centered items 12px too far to the left for example. You can check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/cy60te86/4/

Comment: Another approach would be using flexbox (justify-content) to center the whole nav div and then take the elements, which should be on the right side out of the flow with position: absolute - then you need to hardcode the right side items (lastt item right: 0 // second last item: right 0 + itemlegnth + padding // third last item: right 0 + itemlegnth(*2) + padding (*2) -- a little bit dirty, but once you calculate the position it works like a charm. When you take items out of the content flow, the flexbox automatically center the remaining items.

Comment: @DoUtDes Thank you for the detailed explanation. But now menu items are placed in the center of space between the logo and the right-hand side menu ([view image `A`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uX70c.png)). Is it what you need? I thought you want to place these items in the center of the Navbar (image `B`).

Comment: @GlebKemarsky ah, you´re right. I want the result of B. Do you have any idea what is causing this? Seems to be a problem with the floated items and the logo, since they somehow suppress the container. If I try the other way with the flexbox approach (https://jsfiddle.net/dmb6a0au/4/), this problem seems not to be present. Would be nice to know, if it is possible to achieve the result of B with text-align center for my knowledge ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the last three li by nth-child selector and float them to right.

Comment: Hi, I've already tried that, it could be possible that I have to go to the optician to get some glasses, but I am not sure, if the centered items are really centered when the other itmes are floated to the right. I've made a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/37gc2v9x/. While I am sure that the items are centered when the whole div is centered, I am not sure, if they items are really centered when the other itmes are floated to right? May you check please, if it is just some kind of optical illusion? For me they seems not to be centered. You may also check my css comments for understanding :)

Comment: It looks center, however logo is within the container so from left side it seems not centered but centered actually.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't get it right here's something for you to work around.

```
<style>
    .header {
      height: 100px;
      overflow: visible;
      padding: 0px;
    }

    .row {
        position: relative;
        width: 120%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .logo {
      display: inline-block;
      width: auto;
      float: left;
     }

    .main-menu {
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 200;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 50px;
    }

     #menu-mainnav {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: block;
    }

    #menu-mainnav > li {
     float: left;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     position: relative;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: list-item;
     text-align: match-parent;
     padding-right:11px;
      }

    #menu-mainnav > li > a {
     font-size: 11px;
     display: block;
     box-sizing: content-box;
     }
    .spacer {
        width: 30%;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="logo" data-margin-top="34px" data-margin-       bottom="10px" data-margin-left="0px" data-margin-right="0px"> <a class="logo-link" href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <img src="http://www.backstein.com/media/mobil_1376659435_test_logo_neu.jpg" alt="ava" class="logo-1x standard-logo" style="" height="38" width="51"> </a> </div>
      <table width="92%" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="85%" height="38"><table width="109%" height="25" border="0" align="right">
            <tr>
              <td width="47%" height="21">&nbsp;</td>
              <td width="53%" align="right"> <ul id="menu-mainnav" class="menu"  style="float:none;">
                <li id="menu-item-116" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-116 dropdown-menu"> <a href="/link1/" aria-haspopup="true"> <span class="menu-text">CENTER </span></a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-116 dropdown-menu"> <a href="/link1/" aria-haspopup="true"> <span class="menu-text">CENTER </span></a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-2" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-116 dropdown-menu"> <a href="/link1/" aria-haspopup="true"> <span class="menu-text">CENTER </span></a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-3" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-116 dropdown-menu"> <a href="/link1/" aria-haspopup="true"> <span class="menu-text">CENTER </span></a></li>
                <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"></a></ul></td>
              </tr>
          </table></td>
          <td width="15%" align="left"><table width="213" border="0" align="right"  class="menu">
            <tr>
              <td width="56%" height="21" align="right"><ul id="menu-mainnav" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-5" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76"> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="menu-text">TO RIGHT </span></a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76"> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="menu-text">TO RIGHT &nbsp; </span></a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-133" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-133 menu-item-button"> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="menu-textmenu-text button button-default button-medium">TO RIGHT </span></a></li>
              </ul></td>
              </tr>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <p>&nbsp;</div>
    </div></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Divide the menu into two parts.
2. Simplify the `.main-menu` class.
3. Use `position:absolute; left:0; right:0;` to extend the block to the width of its parent.
4. Add `text-align: center;` to place items in the center of the block.

Please check the result: https://jsfiddle.net/glebkema/0on8za7q/

```css
.header {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 0px;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  width: 94.44444%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}

.main-menu {
  position: relative;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}

.menu > li {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: list-item;
  text-align: match-parent;
  padding-right: 11px;
}
.menu > li {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu > li > a {
  font-size: 11px;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.menu-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu-right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" style="height: 100px; overflow: visible;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="logo" data-margin-top="34px" data-margin-bottom="10px" data-margin-left="0px" data-margin-right="0px">
      <a class="logo-link" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
        <img src="http://www.backstein.com/media/mobil_1376659435_test_logo_neu.jpg" alt="ava" class="logo-1x standard-logo" style="" height="33" width="45">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="main-menu">

      <ul id="menu-mainnav-1" class="menu menu-center">
        <li id="menu-item-116" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-116 dropdown-menu">
          <a href="/link1/" aria-haspopup="true">
            <span class="menu-text">CENTER </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-263" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-263 dropdown-menu">
          <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" aria-haspopup="true">
            <span class="menu-text">CENTER </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-75" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-75">
          <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
            <span class="menu-text">CENTER </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27">
          <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
            <span class="menu-text">CENTER </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76">
          <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
            <span class="menu-text">CENTER </span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <ul id="menu-mainnav-2" class="menu menu-right">
        <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76">
          <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
            <span class="menu-text">TO RIGHT </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76">
          <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">
            <span class="menu-text">TO RIGHT </span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-133" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-133 menu-item-button">
          <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="menu-textmenu-text button button-default button-medium">TO RIGHT
                        </span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This also was my thought, but in that case I'd to change the markup within the php-files. I am using a child theme, it would not have been impossible, but I was looking for another solution, without touching the markup given bei the Theme's Author. But thank you for you suggestions, which would have been my last solution for this conflict

Comment: @DoUtDes Thank you for explanation. The practical side of affairs makes your issue even more interesting.

Comment: @DoUtDes Please tell me again the details, what you can change in the code and what is not.