# Use flexbox to align 2 divs: one center-center and the other bottom center

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to use flexbox to align two divs within their parent with one completely centered and the other bottom-center. They both share the same parent div. The result should be like this:

```
------------------------
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|                      |
|        ------        |
|        | b1 |        |
|        |    |        |
|        ------        |
|                      |
|        ------        |
|        | b2 |        |
|        ------        |
------------------------
```

This is what I have so far:

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px black solid;
}

.text-center{
  text-align:center;
}

.flex-wrap {
  width:400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start; 
}

.flex-centered {
  align-self: center;
}

.flex-bottom-center {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrap">
  <div class="flex-centered text-center">
    Here is some text for the center
  </div>
    
  <div class="flex-bottom-center text-center">
    Here is some text for the bottom center
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems almost there but the first box is left aligned whilst the bottom is right aligned.

Can anyone help?

**Edit**: this is not the same as the question cited in marking mine as duplicate: that question is asking how to make the bottom `div` equidistant to the center `div` and the bottom. Mine is asking how to place the bottom `div` at the bottom of the container.

Comment: No this is not possible ***natively*** with Flexbox. I can be done by adding a dummy hidden div the same size as the footer to balance out the margins.

Comment: Essentially, it's the same as this question...different direction, same issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700805/aligning-elements-left-and-center-with-flexbox

Comment: In reference to your edit, the duplicate is valid, as with only a minor adjustment it meets the requirements of your question. I've updated [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33944865/3597276) to show exactly how it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can change to `flex-direction: column` and then you can use margins to position `divs`

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
.text-center{
  text-align:center;
}

.flex-wrap {
  width:400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.flex-centered, .flex-bottom-center {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrap">
  <div class="flex-centered text-center">Here is some text for the center</div>
  <div class="flex-bottom-center text-center">Here is some text for the bottom center</div>
</div>
```

If you want to position `.flex-centered` in vertical center of parent element you need to remove it from elements flow with `position: absolute`

```css
div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px black solid;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.flex-wrap {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
}
.flex-centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrap">
  <div class="flex-centered text-center">Here is some text for the center</div>
  <div class="flex-bottom-center text-center">Here is some text for the bottom center</div>
</div>
```