# How to center position targeted element in flexbox group

Tags: css, reactjs, chakra-ui

I have a flexbox grouping consisting of two elements. The first is an arrow icon and the other is text. I want the items to be center aligned vertically. However, horizontally, I want the arrow to be left aligned and the text to be perfectly centered in the parent (flex) container. How can I accomplish this?

As you can see in the code, I tried using the `alignSelf` property on the `Text` element. However, as you can see in the screenshot I shared, that did not work. I am using the Chakra UI library. Here is the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-zeh-y99i7k?file=/src/App.js:190-369).

```
import { Flex, Text } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { ArrowBackIcon } from "@chakra-ui/icons";

<Flex alignItems="center" background="grey">
  <ArrowBackIcon boxSize="32px" />
  <Text fontSize="24px" fontWeight={700} alignSelf="center">
    Confirm Your Information
  </Text>
</Flex>
```

[image]

Comment: The linked duplicate provides several valid strategies. I like the [pseudo-element solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52177798/1264804) best for your case.

Comment: Note that this was never really a React question. It could've been presented as a simple HTML structure instead, vastly simplifying the problem.